# Easy way to add a drawer item with custom onPress?

Tags: react-navigation

I'm using DrawerNavigator and, as long as I want to navigate to a new screen, all's fine.

Now I want to add a drawer item which does not navigate to a new screen but simply triggers an action (in general). Specifically, I want to use 'react-native' Share functionality.

I got this to work but I think the solution is not a very good one. Here's what I got so far:

```jsx
const myContentComponent = props => (
    <ScrollView alwaysBounceVertical={false}>
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }} forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
            <DrawerItems {...props} />
            <TouchableItem
                key="share"
                onPress={() => {
                    Share.share(
                        {
                            message: 'YO: this will be the text message',
                            url: 'http://tmp.com',
                            title: 'This will be the email title/subject',
                        },
                        {
                            // Android only:
                            dialogTitle: 'This will be the title in the dialog to choose means of sharing',
                        },
                    );
                    props.navigation.navigate('DrawerClose');
                }}
                delayPressIn={0}
            >
                <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ left: 'always', right: 'never', vertical: 'never' }}>
                    <View style={[{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }, {}]}>
                        <View style={[{ marginHorizontal: 16, width: 24, alignItems: 'center' }, { opacity: 0.62 }, {}]}>
                            <Icon name="share" />
                        </View>
                        <Text style={[{ margin: 16, fontWeight: 'bold' }, { color: DrawerItems.defaultProps.inactiveTintColor }]}>Share</Text>
                    </View>
                </SafeAreaView>
            </TouchableItem>
        </SafeAreaView>
    </ScrollView>
);

const RootStack = DrawerNavigator(
    {
        Settings: {
            screen: SettingsScreen,
        },
    },
    {
        contentComponent: myContentComponent,
    },
);
```

Basically, I am creating a new `contentComponent` based off of the default:

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/v1.5.8/src/navigators/DrawerNavigator.js#L16-L22

I am copying the styles and element structure of a normal drawer item (everything under `TouchableItem`) - all this so I can define my own `onPress` which does the share logic and closes the drawer.

There has to be a better way right? What happens if I want the "Share" drawer item somewhere amongst the drawer items rendered by `DrawerItems` (the ones that support navigation)? Right now I can only work around the items rendered by `DrawerItems`. Besides, copying so much code from react-navigation seems like really bad form.

I just want an item which does some custom logic instead of rendering a screen.

Comment: are you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure will it be helpful?

I used onPress event for logout like this way. It's no need to render a new DrawerItems

```js
const DrawerNavigator = createAppContainer(createDrawerNavigator({

  Logout: {
    screen: EmptyScreenForLogoutConfirmation,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarLabel: 'Logout',
      drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name={"ios-cog"} size={26} />,

    }),
  },
}, 
{
  contentComponent:(props ) => (
    <DrawerItems {...props} 
      onItemPress = {
        ( route ) =>       
        {    
          if (route.route.routeName !== "Logout") {
            props.onItemPress(route);
            return;
          }
          return Alert.alert(   // Shows up the alert without redirecting anywhere
            'Confirmation required'
            ,'Do you really want to logout?'
            ,[
              {text: 'No'},
              {text: 'Yes', onPress: () => { props.navigation.navigate('Logedout'); }},
            ]
          )
        }
      }
    />
  ),
  contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
  }
},))
```